# what is the difference between const nav: typechecking = useNavigation() and const nav = useNavigation<typechecking>()?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

so I recently switched to Typescript from Javascript in React Native and I had a question while type checking the `useNavigation` hook.

```
const nav: typechecking = useNavigation()
```

and

```
const nav = useNavigation<typechecking>()
```

they both work for my code, but I was thinking about the difference between them?

But, what is the correct explanation for this?

Like, what i could think was that because `useNavigation()` hook could have many return types, we have restricted he return type to `typechecking` in the 2nd one.
While in the 1st one, we are receiving all the types from `useNavigation()` hook but are checking nav for `typechecking` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR** There is no difference.

---

The following is an [explicit type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables). You tell the compiler that `nav` has a specified type `typechecking` (You usually want to write types with a Capital).

```
const nav: typechecking = useNavigation()
```

---

This has no explicit type annotation and the type of `nav` is inferred automatically by the compiler based on the return type of `useNavigation<typechecking>()`. Instead you pass a generic argument to the function that probably, depending on the function declaration, affects it's return type .

```
const nav = useNavigation<typechecking>()
```

We can confirm this assumption by taking a look at the declaration ([source code on Github](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/8d2a6d8ef642872d3d506dca483b7474471a040c/packages/core/src/useNavigation.tsx#L12)). You'll see that the function returns the generic argument `T`.

```
export function useNavigation<
  T = NavigationProp<ReactNavigation.RootParamList>
>(): T {
  // implementation
}
```

As mentioned above, now the type of `nav` will be inferred automatically based on the return type of `useNavigation()` which is whatever you pass as a generic argument.